# Chrome JavaScript source maps

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a single page EmberJS app & use npm (package.json) & bower.json files

My question is for debugging purposes in Chrome using JavaScript source maps, is there some devtools npm package that I can install under my project? How can I do that?

I have the JS source map settings enabled for Chrome devtools.

Answer (score 0):

As source maps are only necessary when combining and/or minimizing your JavaScript code, tools that combine and minimize code usually provide options to generate source maps as well. For external libraries, source maps should be available as well.

Source maps live next to the mimimized JavaScript file names yourJavaScript.js.map